# Drag and Drop content from one grid-child to another

Tags: c#, wpf, button, drag-and-drop, grid

I'm looking for a way to let the user of my program move a button (which as an image as background, and is the content of a Grid-Children) to another Grid-Children by drag-and-drop.

My Buttons are created by the program itself based on a database in a for-iteration:

```
foreach (PC_Infos item in allPcsOnThisFloor)
{
    if (item != null)
    {
        roomToCoordinates(allPcsOnThisFloor[i].Room,out column, out row);
        Button btn = new Button();
        btn.Name = Name+ "_Button";
        btn.Background = new ImageBrush(my icon here);
        btn.Click += btn_Click;
        btn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, column);
        btn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, row);
        My_Grid.Children.Add (btn);
        i++;
    }
    else 
        break;
}
```

`PC_Infos` is just a class holding the Properties: PC_Name, Room and MAC_adress nothing else.

My Grid:

```
<Grid x:Name="Grid_10" AllowDrop="True">
    <Grid.Background>
        <ImageBrush ImageSource="C:\Users\XXX\XXX\buildingPlan.png"/>
    </Grid.Background>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        [...]
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        [...]
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
</Grid>
```

Now is there a way to use a `btn.*` which fetches the current position (Row and Column) when dragged, and another `btn.*` which creates a new copy of this button in the Grid-Child the mouse is currently over when the mouse drops the button?
Or is there even a way to 'move' the button from one Child to another?

BTW: My Program should show a building plan with PCs as icons(buttons) on it at the place they actually are. A rough guess is takes by the source code by reading the column "Room" in my db. But a room isn't just one place. Someone works at the window another on at the door, this should be marked by user (with drag&drop)
I'm using a WPF-Application in VS'13 with C# and .Net 4.5.1.

PS: If there is anybody who says: Why Grid and why the hell buttons? :D : When the User clicks on the icon a new window with system value such as OS, RAM, CPU... will show up. But I'm open for any implementation. I haven't done programming for so long now, so I may not know the best way.

[While I'm not allowed to post images with 0 Rep, here is a Link to an img which shows my Grid over my buildingplan http://alexander.valerius.wilhelm-gym.net/Grid.PNG](http://alexander.valerius.wilhelm-gym.net/Grid.PNG)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may misunderstand your problem but as far as I can see, there no drag'n'drop here : you want to move `UIElements` all around your `Panel`.

First, I would recommand using a `Canvas` to display your items rather than a `Grid` as it will offer much more flexibility.

Let's say you have this class as your main object :

```
public class PC_Infos
{
    public string PC_Name;
    public string Room;
    public string MAC_Adress;
}
```

Rather than building controls in code-behind, I prefer a simple wrapper like :

```
public class DragablePC : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public DragablePC(PC_Infos pc, double x = 0d, double y = 0d)
    {
        _pcItem = pc;
        PcRow = y;
        PcColumn = x;
    }

    private double _x;
    public double PcColumn
    {
        get { return _x; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _x) return;
            _x = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PcColumn");
        }
    }

    private double _y;
    public double PcRow
    {
        get { return _y; }
        set
        {
            if (value == _y) return;
            _y = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("PcRow");
        }
    }

    PC_Infos _pcItem;

    public DragablePC(PC_Infos pc, double x = 0d, double y = 0d)
    {
        _pcItem = pc;
        PcRow = y;
        PcColumn = x;
    }

    public override string ToString() { return _pcItem.PC_Name; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
    }
}
```

This wrapper simply stores X/Y coordinates and your item. It allows to define a binding source as follows :

```
AllPCS = allPcsOnThisFloor.Select(p => new DragablePC(p));
```

Now, you can use an `ItemsControl` to display your items. As stated above, I will use a `Canvas` for the `ItemsPanel` and define a simple `ItemContainerStyle` to place them onto it.

```
    <ItemsControl Name="DDPanel" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllPCS}"
                  MouseMove="DDPanel_MouseMove">
        <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                <Canvas IsItemsHost="True" Background="LightGray"/>                    
            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=PcRow}"/>
                <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=PcColumn}"/>
            </Style>
        </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type dnd:DragablePC}">
                <Border BorderBrush="Red" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="6" Padding="6, 12"
                        Background="White" MinWidth="70" 
                        MouseLeftButtonDown="Border_MouseLeftButtonDown"
                        MouseLeftButtonUp="Border_MouseLeftButtonUp">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                </Border>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
```

The `ItemTemplate` has to be updated to suit your needs, most important part being the handling of mouse events.

Here are the handlers I've added :

```
    DragablePC _selected = null;
    Point cursorPos = new Point();

    private void DDPanel_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (null == _selected) return;

        Point newPosition = e.GetPosition(DDPanel);
        _selected.PcColumn += newPosition.X - cursorPos.X;
        _selected.PcRow += newPosition.Y - cursorPos.Y;
        cursorPos = newPosition;
    }

    private void Border_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiItem = sender as FrameworkElement;
        var dpc = uiItem.DataContext as DragablePC;

        if (dpc == null) return;

        cursorPos = e.GetPosition(DDPanel);
        _selected = dpc;
    }

    private void Border_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var uiItem = sender as FrameworkElement;
        var dpc = uiItem.DataContext as DragablePC;

        if (dpc == null) return;

        _selected = null;
    }
```

This now needs a lot of tweaking such as handling `MouseLeave` event, adding some logic to the positionning... but you can now move your PC all around.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank's for the second paragraph :D Now I use a canvas which is (as you already metioned) much more flexible and easier and instead of Buttons I use now Rectangles. With the  `MyCanvas_MouseDown`, `MyCanvas_MouseMove` and `MyCanvas_MouseMove` ActionHandlers and a global Variable _DragInProgress_, I can handle the Movements. When `MouseDown` is called the code gets the underlaying rectangle and redraws it while `MouseMove` with deltaX and deltaY of the mouse since pressing any mouseButton down.

Comment: Sorry for not using your code or the way you would have done it, but look at my questinon's PS. I'm relativly new to programming and to be honest I don't even understand every bit of your code. But you gave me a new direction

Comment: Glad it could help. If you're on WPF, you definitely should give an eye on binding and templating.